# Multiple oddities with Scheme graphics

Tags: graphics, scheme

Perhaps against my better judgement, I decided to try to get graphics working in scheme.
(MIT/GNU)

To get it started, I wrote

```
(define graphics-types (enumerate-graphics-types))
(define graphics (make-graphics-device (car graphics-types)))
```

which popped up a white window. Calling

```
(graphics-draw-point graphics .5 0)
```

gave the expected result, which was that a little black pixel appeared 3/4 of the way to the right of the window (vertically in the center). However, calling

```
(graphics-erase-point graphics .5 0)
```

did nothing. Furthermore, minimizing and restoring the window erased the point, but experimentation showed that minimizing always cleared the entire window.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: How attached are you to MIT Scheme? If the answer is "not very", you might consider Racket, which has a GUI library, extensive documentation, and an active user mailing list.

Comment: Pretty attached. I was asking the question in part to see if this is a bug or if I'm just being stupid somewhere. In any case, I don't think I'll switch, (among other things) because of the debian package support that mit/gnu scheme has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `graphics-erase-point` procedure in MIT Scheme works by changing the drawing mode to 0, calling `graphics-draw-point`, then changing the drawing mode back to whatever it was before. More information on the mechanics of MIT Scheme drawing modes can be found at [MIT's drawing mode documentation](http://sicp.ai.mit.edu/Fall-2004/manuals/scheme-7.5.5/doc/scheme_18.html#SEC187)

The bug appears to be in the `graphics-bind-drawing-mode` procedure, which is used in `graphics-erase-point` to change the drawing mode. The easiest solution is to redefine `graphics-erase-point` to use `graphics-set-drawing-mode` instead. The resulting code looks like this:

```
(define (graphics-erase-point device x y)
  (graphics-set-drawing-mode device 0)
  (graphics-draw-point device x y)
  (graphics-set-drawing-mode device 15))
```

15 is the default drawing mode, which I've used for the sake of simplicity, but it is certainly possible to intelligently revert drawing modes (I leave that exercise for you).

Comment: This fails, complaining that `device` is not a bound variable. If I define it to something which is not a graphics device, it tells me that it is not the correct type of record.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my answer and this new code should work.

Comment: The 0 and 15 should be interchanged.

Comment: No they shouldn't. Drawing mode 0 means to use the background color, which will allow us to erase. Drawing mode 15 means use the foreground color, which allows us to draw again (otherwise we would just stay in erase mode).

Comment: Well, it works for me if I interchange them, and doesn't if I use what you have.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be argumentative - I can change the answer if you'd like. This is MIT Scheme we are dealing with, it's not a surprise that the drawing modes are wonky on some systems. I figured I should keep the answer as is since it is correct according to the specifications and works on my system, and is therefore the preferable answer to have up here for posterity.

Comment: So it works like that on your system? Alright, leave it as is- you're right about posterity. Thanks!